# sikuli execution error after uninstall java jre8 and install Amazon Corretto jdk11.0.13_8

Tags: java, java-11, sikuli

there is the execution script which I have placed the jdk11.0.13_8 in execution directory:

```
@echo off

REM temp fix to avoid using zulu java 10
set JAVA_HOME=%~dp0\jdk11.0.13_8


SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set SJAR=sikulix

if not defined SIKULIX_HOME goto NOHOME
if EXIST "%SIKULIX_HOME%%SJAR%.jar" goto YESHOME
if not EXIST "%SIKULIX_HOME%\%SJAR%.jar" goto BADHOME
set SJAR=\sikulix

:BADHOME
echo +++ SIKULIX_HOME specified but not useable %SIKULIX_HOME%

:NOHOME
set SIKULIX_HOME=%~dp0

:YESHOME
set PARMS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine

if not defined JAVA_HOME goto CHECKJAVA
IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA_OK
echo +++ JAVA_HOME specified but not useable %JAVA_HOME%
echo +++ looking for Java in system path and then in standard places

:CHECKJAVA
java 2> nul
if errorlevel 9009 goto CHECKPLACES
goto JAVA_OK_PATH

:CHECKPLACES
set PROGRAMS=%ProgramFiles%
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) set PROGRAMS32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA7
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre8
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA7
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA6
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA6
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" goto JAVANO
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO
if not defined PROGRAMS32 goto JAVANO32

IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA732
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre8
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA732
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" goto JAVA632
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre7
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVA632
IF not EXIST "%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" goto JAVANO32
set JAVA_HOME=%PROGRAMS32%\Java\jre6
goto JAVA_OK

:JAVANO32
echo +++ Java not found in standard places %PROGRAMS% or %PROGRAMS32%
echo +++ JAVA_HOME not specified
goto STOPIT

:JAVA_OK_PATH
echo +++ running this Java
set SIKULI_COMMAND=%*
java -version
PATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%libs;%PATH%
echo +++ trying to run SikuliX
echo +++ using: %PARMS% -jar %SIKULIX_HOME%%SJAR%.jar %SIKULI_COMMAND%
java %PARMS% -jar "%SIKULIX_HOME%%SJAR%.jar" %SIKULI_COMMAND%
GOTO FINALLY

:JAVA_OK
echo +++ running this Java
set SIKULI_COMMAND=%*
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version
PATH=%SIKULIX_HOME%libs;%PATH%
echo +++ trying to run SikuliX
echo +++ using: %PARMS% -jar %SIKULIX_HOME%%SJAR%.jar %SIKULI_COMMAND%
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" %PARMS% -jar "%SIKULIX_HOME%%SJAR%.jar" %SIKULI_COMMAND%
GOTO FINALLY

:STOPIT
echo.+++ ended with some errors
:FINALLY
ENDLOCAL
```

I execute the file in cmd, error:

```
C:\SikuliX>runsikulix.cmd
+++ running this Java
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.13.8.1 (build 11.0.13+8-LTS, mixed mode)
+++ trying to run SikuliX
+++ using: -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine -jar C:\SikuliX\sikulix.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.sikuli.basics.Debug.log(Debug.java:697)
        at org.sikuli.basics.Debug.logx(Debug.java:675)
        at org.sikuli.script.RunTime.log(RunTime.java:99)
        at org.sikuli.script.RunTime.get(RunTime.java:184)
        at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE.run(SikuliIDE.java:177)
        at org.sikuli.ide.Sikulix.main(Sikulix.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at org.sikuli.basics.Settings.<clinit>(Settings.java:123)
        ... 6 more
```